# Gradle dependencies on "Google open source repository" projects

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Is there any way how to add **gradle dependency** on project from [Google Git](https://android.googlesource.com/)?

For example, if I want to use [color-picker](http://www.materialdoc.com/color-picker/) I have to clone repository, import module and add it as project dependency.

Comment: See if somebody [packaged it as a library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/18?sort=created).

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for tip.